# Building a Geo Targeting in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, clregion

Im trying to implement geo targeting functionality with CLRegion. But When I run this app the MKCircle didn't show up, can anyone tell me which part is wrong?

```
 func setupData(){
    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion.self){

    let tripspotRegion = [
        tripSpot( title: "一中商圈", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.149062, 120.684891), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "台中一中", type: "food"),
        tripSpot( title: "逢甲夜市", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.180407, 120.645086), regionRadius: 300.0, location:"台中逢甲", type: "food"),
        tripSpot( title: "東海商圈", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.181143, 120.593158), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "東海商圈", type: "food")]
    //set annotation
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let regionRadius = 300.0
    let title = "title"
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude,longitude: coordinate.longitude), radius: regionRadius, identifier: title)
    //set annotation
    let tripSpotAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    tripSpotAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
    tripSpotAnnotation.title = "\(title)"
    mapView.addAnnotations(tripspotRegion)
   locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    // draw a circle
        let circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)

        mapView.addOverlay(circle)
    }
    // check if can monitor region
        else{

            print("system can't track regions")



           }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay)` ?  Also, you haven't provided a latitude or longitude for `coordinate`

Comment: yes I have implemented mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay), but annotation show currently so how should I provided a latitude and longitude for coordinate currently?

Comment: You have defined three coordinates in your `tripspotRegion` array.  Perhaps you could use one of those as the center? Otherwise your region will be at 0,0

Comment: I see, Im trying to make multiple annotations on map with each own MKCircle. Can that be possible?

Comment: Yes, you need to add multiple annotations, perhaps by looping over the `tripSpotRegion` array

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you means, can you please describe more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put three coordinates in an array, but then you aren't doing anything with them.  You are creating a new `coordinate` but not initialising it, so your region and overlay will be at (0,0).  I think you meant to use the `tripspotArray` to add the regions/overlays:

```
func setupData(){
    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion.self) {

        let tripspotRegion = [
            tripSpot( title: "一中商圈", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.149062, 120.684891), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "台中一中", type: "food"),
            tripSpot( title: "逢甲夜市", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.180407, 120.645086), regionRadius: 300.0, location:"台中逢甲", type: "food"),
            tripSpot( title: "東海商圈", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.181143, 120.593158), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "東海商圈", type: "food")]

        for aSpot in tripspotRegion {
            //set annotation
            let coordinate =aSpot.coordindate
            let regionRadius = aSpot.regionRadius
            let title = aSpot.title
            let region = CLCircularRegion(center: coordinate, radius: regionRadius, identifier: title)
//set annotation
            let tripSpotAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            tripSpotAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
            tripSpotAnnotation.title = title
            mapView.addAnnotations([tripSpotAnnotation])
            locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
// draw a circle
            let circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)
            mapView.addOverlay(circle)
        }
    } else{
        print("system can't track regions")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so so much! this is exactly what i want! more important I'm now realize the main ideal of it. Appreciate !